# How to stop analytics tracking GET variables?

Tags: google-analytics

Google tracks every GET variable as a single page.

```
1 visit - example.com/register.php?ref=6
1 visit - example.com/register.php?ref=12
1 visit - example.com/register.php?ref=2
```

Is it possible to disable the tracking of GET variables?

```
3 visits - example.com/register.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google Help Page](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55499) has an answer (copied from there):

1. Sign in to your account at http://www.google.com/analytics (or click the
   Reporting tab in your AdWords account and click 'Google Analytics').
   The Analytics Settings page appears.
2. Find the applicable profile in
   the Website Profiles table and click Edit. The Profile Settings page
   appears.
3. Click Edit from the Main Website Profile Information table.
4. In the Exclude URL Query Parameters field, enter the parameters to
   remove from your reports (ex: sid, sessionid, vid). Separate each
   parameter with a comma.

If you only need to exclude certain
    parameters under particular conditions, or would like to replace a
    parameter with a placeholder, you'll need to create an advanced
    filter to re-write the URL.